# Program keeps failing bc of list index out of range error

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am doing an assignment for school and I keep failing. I think my solution mostly makes sense but the code has a problem that I don't know how to fix.

The problem is the following:

- Write a function modify_column(m, i, l) that takes three arguments: a matrix m, an index i and a list l.
- The function should replace values in the i-th column of the matrix by values from the list l.

My idea is the following: First pop all the excess elements of l so two lists are the same length. 
Then, while l is non empty, iterate through matrix m and then take the i-th element of each row and change it into the first element of the list l and then pop the first element off the list l.

Code:

```
my_matrix = [
[ 5,  4,  6, -3],
[ 4,  7, 10,  9],
[12,  6, 11,  5],
[ 2, -2,  1,  3],
[ 1,  7, -1,  5],    
]
def modify_column(m, i, l):
    if len(l) >= len(m): 
        while len(l) != len(m) :
            l.pop()
    print(l)
    while l != []:
        for el in m: 
            el[i] = l[0]
            l.pop(0)
    return m
print(modify_column(my_matrix, 2, [2, -5, 6]))
```

It keeps returning this error:

```
print(modify_column(my_matrix, 2, [2, -5, 6]))
File "/home/tdota/Desktop/Faks/CS_1/MyScripts/manipulating_matrices.py", line 35, in modify_column
el[i] = l[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please give a sense to your variables names, it could useful when other review your code like now ;)

Comment: The inner "for el in m" loop exhausts "l" before the outer "while l != []" even sees it.

Comment: How do you replace 1 value by a list of value ? What am i missing ?

Comment: I think the list you give you have the same size of a column, so of sublist

Comment: I think you're looking to swap the indentation of `while l != []: for el in m:`? As it stands now, you check your list one, then proceed to pop elements and run into the issue of trying to index the empty list as len(l) is 3, but `m` has a length of 5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You though about the case the values are bigger, but that's not where the problem is : when vaues are smaller you can for example add random values. Also don't need to clear your `values` just increase an index, also use good names and you're done :

```
def modify_column(matrix, index, values):
    if len(values) < len(matrix):
        while len(values) != len(matrix):
            values.append(randint(0, 10))

    for idx, row in enumerate(matrix):
        row[index] = values[idx]
    return matrix
---------------------
initial
[[5, 4, 6, -3], [4, 7, 10, 9], [12, 6, 11, 5], [2, -2, 1, 3], [1, 7, -1, 5]]

modify_column(my_matrix, 2, [2, -5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4])
[[5, 4, 2, -3], [4, 7, -5, 9], [12, 6, 6, 5], [2, -2, 1, 3], [1, 7, 2, 5]]
        ^               ^              ^               ^             ^
modify_column(my_matrix, 2, [2, -5, 6]) # add random value to fill
[[5, 4, 2, -3], [4, 7, -5, 9], [12, 6, 6, 5], [2, -2, 10, 3], [1, 7, 4, 5]]
        ^               ^              ^               ^             ^
```

Comment: The thing is that I can't be adding random values because the problem says so :/, but your solution gave me an idea on how to solve the problem so I'll be doing that now and closing the discussion on this one. Sorry for my variable names, I have to have the function as defined in the exercise( here it is modify_column(m,i,l)) I will try to not use names like those when asking questions :).

Comment: @todor2512 I think the names you have are just to explain the exercice, but I hope you're free to give whatever name you want because that's ust a better code practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

your for loop continues to run until the end and after that your while condition is applied to the "l" array. so you have to take it out:

```
my_matrix = [
[ 5,  4,  6, -3],
[ 4,  7, 10,  9],
[12,  6, 11,  5],
[ 2, -2,  1,  3],
[ 1,  7, -1,  5],    
]
def modify_column(m, i, l):
    index = 0 # this will count your m rows
    if len(l) >= len(m): 
        while len(l) != len(m) :
            l.pop()
    print(l)
    while l != []:
        m[index][i] = l[0]
        l.pop(0)
        index = index + 1
    return m
print(modify_column(my_matrix, 2, [2, -5, 6]))
```

the output will be:

[[5, 4, 2, -3], [4, 7, -5, 9], [12, 6, 6, 5], [2, -2, 1, 3], [1, 7, -1, 5]]